# How to display service base databse into a combobox c#

Tags: c#

can someone explain how this work ? since I wanted to display the database in the combo box but when I find the code I still somehow doesn't understand how it work. im trying to make a combo Box that display rooms so that the user can choose one of them and update in the database so that the person who see all the reservation knows wha time and what date the user pick so there isnt any same schedule.

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  
using System.Data.SqlClient;  
  
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1  
{  
    public partial class Form1 : Form  
    {  
        public Form1()  
        {  
            InitializeComponent();  
            refreshdata();  
        }  
        public void refreshdata()     
        {  
            DataRow dr;  
  
  
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=NiluNilesh;Initial Catalog=mynewdata;Integrated Security=True");  
            con.Open();  
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_data", con);  
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);  
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
            sda.Fill(dt);  
  
            dr = dt.NewRow();  
            dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 0, "--Select Movie--" };  
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);  
             
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";  
          
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "movie";  
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;  
              
            con.Close();   
        }           
    }       
}
```

im trying to work with the service based database so that it can work with the combo box but still trying to figure out each of the function. can someone help me :) .

Comment: Delete the three lines of code after `da.Fill(dt);` and then decide if you want to show rooms or movies

Comment: sorry what i meant is movie not rooms